# make UITextField placeholder text bold

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have set placeholder for UITextField in the Interface Builder. Now, how do i make the placeholder text bold.?

Comment: then won't be placeholder......

Answer (score 5):

Please Use Following code for Your Problem.

```
    UIColor *color = [UIColor blackColor];
    UIFont* boldFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
    [self.textField setFont:boldFont];
    self.textField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Test" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color}];
```

May This help to lot.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do it is, If you change the property(font,size etc) of your `UITextField` it'll be applied to your placeholder as well. Just change the property of your `UITextField` and see the effect.

EDIT :

And then in your `UITextField` delegate method set this property to normal again.

Comment: yeah but that will also effect the text that i enter in the textfield.  i want only the placeholder to be bold and not the text

Comment: kool..tnx..or i can use a label as a placeholder. and do however i want and hide the label in uitextfield delgate..is this a bad approach?

Comment: @Arun You can absolutely use the label as placeholder. That's how we achieve placeholder in UITextView. It's not a bad approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
    [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
}
```